# Display string as underscores but keeping value

Tags: c#, regex, windows-phone-7

I am writing a basic hangman game. I want to store a string Word as the word to be found by the user. My problem is that I want to display this word as underscores (like you do in a paper hangman) but keep it's string value. A friend of mine said this could be done via Regex but researching it doesn't seem to help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Farinha, but using `HashSet`

Some importang points: we are using a `HashSet` because in the end the letters can have two states: discovered (present in the HS) or not discovered (not present). We initialize the `HashSet` passing as a parameter `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` because we consider `L` and `l` to be the same thing. To use the `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` we have to use an `HashSet<string>` (an HS of `string`s) instead of an `HashSet<char>` (an HS of `char`s). So when using the `discovered.Contains()` we have to convert the `c` `char` in a `string` with a `ToString`

```
static string ConvertWord(string word, HashSet<string> discovered)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word.Length);

    foreach (char c in word)
    {
        if (discovered.Contains(c.ToString()))
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append('_');
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

HashSet<string> discovered = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

// The "secret" word
string word = "Hello world";

// How to add letters to the ones discovered
discovered.Add("l");

// The word ready to be shown
string convertWord = ConvertWord(word, discovered);
```

We could have done the ConvertWord in much less characters, but for today it's enough :-)

Ok... I'll give you an example, in C# 4.0:

```
static string ConvertWord(string word, HashSet<string> discovered)
{
    return string.Concat(word.Select(p => discovered.Contains(p.ToString()) ? p : '_'));
}
```

Comment: Upon trying your answer I am getting the 'Cannot find type/NS' error on HashSet. I have referenced sys.collections.generic.

Comment: @MaxWillmo What version of C# are you using? This is for C#/.NET >= 3.5 And you must add to the references `System.Core`

Comment: Was missing .Core reference. Thanks

Comment: And now I am back to the same error. Even with the system.core referenced.

Comment: @MaxWillmo This is strange. You know that you must put the code between `HashSet<string> discovered` and `string convertWord...` in a method, right?

Comment: Yes, my code is the exact same as your ideone.com, I have the reference to .Core and collections.generic.

Comment: @MaxWillmo No, the assembly reference is done on the Solution Explorer. There is a pane called References. Check that System.Core is there and if it isn't, add it.

Comment: Found that the WP7 libaries do not have a Hashset. Any other collection I could use to the above method?

Comment: @MaxWillmo Aaaah! :-) `HashSet<string>` => `Dictionary<string, bool>`,  `discovered.Add("l");` => `discovered.Add("l", true);` `discovered.Contains(c.ToString())` => `discovered.ContainsKey(c.ToString())`

Answer (score 1):

Using a Regex doesn't seem like a good approach. I would instead grab the word, break it down into characters, and build a `Dictionary<char,bool>` where the `bool` indicates if the letter has been discovered yet. Then you an look through the `Dictionary` and for each item display the `char` if the letter has been discovered, or an underscore if not.

```
// build the Dictionary
string originalWord = "Stack Overflow";
Dictionary<char, bool> dict = new Dictionary<char, bool>();
for(int i = 0; i < originalWord.Length; i++)
    dict.Add(originalWord[i], false);

// output the current state
string current = "";
foreach(KeyValuePair<char, bool> pair in dict)
{
    current += pair.Value ? pair.Key.ToString() : "_";
}
```

Comment: You  could also use a `HashSet<char>` where the presence of a character in the set indicates whether it has been discovered or not.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can take a look if it is helpful.

The game was simulated by sed and echo. of course, you can use variable for the secret word, not echo as plain text.

say, my secret word is "memory"

```
#user gives a letter "a"

kent$  echo "memory"|sed 's/[^a]/_/g'
______

#user gives a letter "r"
kent$  echo "memory"|sed 's/[^ar]/_/g'
____r_

#user gives a letter "m"
kent$  echo "memory"|sed 's/[^arm]/_/g'
m_m_r_

#user gives a letter "o"
kent$  echo "memory"|sed 's/[^armo]/_/g'
m_mor_

#user gives a letter "x"
kent$  echo "memory"|sed 's/[^armox]/_/g'
m_mor_

#user gives a letter "y" then "e"
kent$  echo "memory"|sed 's/[^armoxy]/_/g'
m_mory

kent$  echo "memory"|sed 's/[^armoxye]/_/g'
memory
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a textbox and having its entry type as password, then set his password character as 'underscore'

Comment: Good idea, but it will not work when I want to change the "_" for a letter that has been found.

Comment: @MaxWillmo - I now get ur point. Is is a windows application?

Comment: WP7 app. Farinha has given a strong answer and I am going to use it. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with regex - you can write a fairly simple function to take an array of characters which represent the guesses made and return the representation of the word as required:

```
    string word = "AMBULANCE";
    public string Hangman(char[] guesses)
    {
        char[] output = new char[word.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            if (guesses.Contains(word[i]))
            {
                output[i] = word[i];
            }
        }
        return new String(output).Replace('\0','_');
    }
```

and then call it using something like:

```
        char[] guesses = new char[] { 'A', 'E' };
        Console.WriteLine(Hangman(guesses));
        Console.ReadLine();
```